# HALCON error #8721: List of bar code models is empty

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have an error in my simple project. I use vb.net 2008 and the full error text is:

```
[HALCON error #8721: List of bar code models is empty at HALCONXLib.HBarCodeXClass.FindBarCode(HImageX Image, Object CodeType, Object& DecodedDataStrings)]
```

And my code is:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports HalconDotNet
Imports Microsoft
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Media
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports HALCONXLib

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim htu As HTupleX = New HTupleX
    Dim reader As HBarCodeX = New HBarCodeX()
    Dim Image As HImageX = New HImageX
    Call Image.ReadImage("d:\barcode\image1.JPG")
    Dim regions As HRegionX = New HRegionX
    Try
        regions = reader.FindBarCode(Image, "EAN-13", htu)
    Catch ex As Exception
        RichTextBox1.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the call to

```
void HBarCodeX.CreateBarCodeModel(
[in] VARIANT GenParamNames, [in] VARIANT GenParamValues)
```

is missing to actually create the Reader.